# nested namespace in C#

Tags: c#

I need to contain a set of static string properties under a namespace such as:

```
namespace1 N1 {
  namespace N2 {
      public const string A = "a";
  }
  public const string B = "c";
  namespace N3 {
      public const string A = "a";
  }
}
```

Is it possible to have nested namespaces in C#? What is the better design approach? Using static classes or using namespaces in this case?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have nested namespaces in C#.

However, it is impossible to have a constant directly inside a namespace. You have to put it into a class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, creating a nested namespace is possible. However, I believe the preferred methodology for something like this would be to [create a resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx)

This gives you the added benefit of being able to change without a code change, as well as to support multiple languages.