# Nested Namespaces in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

What does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466505/258482) to another question mean?

> Yes, creating a nested namespace is possible. However, I believe the
>   preferred methodology for something like this would be to create a
>   resource file
>
> This gives you the added benefit of being able to change without a
>   code change, as well as to support multiple languages.

I am making a few namespaces and I want them to be all under one namespace (`MyNamespace`), but I don't feel like going and changing all the code to add nested interfaces, and naming them `MyNamespace.N1` is not very compatible with intelli-sense.

Edit: My main problem is that `namespace MyNamespace.N1 {  }` does not seem to work right with renames and stuff like that. Is it even a true nested namespace declaration?

Underlying Question: A namespace declaration with a period in it is two namespaces. Why, then, when I rename it, does it not act right with the rename. My question may be vague, but I have such a problem with it that I thought for sure a lot of other people would have run into it. If not, then just close it and I'll try to figure it out some other way.

---

I'm trying to figure out how to put all the namespaces in a project under one namespace. So you would access them using `MyProject.MyN1.MyClass`. If I declare the namespace like `namespace MyProject.MyN1 {  }` and then try to rename it, the intelli-sense only looks at "MyProject" as the namespace, MyN1 is peripheral. But I'm really trying to rename "MyN1" and it doesn't like doing that.

Well, I tried that, and now I'm not sure what my problem was in the first place. As I described it it works fine. I think it was that if I try to add or remove a period in the namespace declaration it doesn't rename it right.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: His answer is related to the use of constants for settings, instead of using a [Resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx). Not to namespaces at all.

Comment: "does not seem to work right with renames and stuff like that" is pretty vague. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: @Dykam, thanks, that's what I was wondering about.

Comment: Perhaps, if you give us an example on what you are doing and what is the result of that action will help us find a way to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that would probably work is to using a global find and replace. What your actually trying to do is to rename two namespaces into one, and it's not going to let you.

Comment: This might be my problem, if it every comes up again I'll revisit this question :)